# PHP curl conversion to coldfusion chfttp

Tags: php, coldfusion, cfhttp, activecampaign

I am looking at this example of activecampaign's event tracking

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://trackcmp.net/event");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
"actid" => "649587205",
"key" => "4a2f544b998d0107cd0341e799513c7eb94abde4",
"event" => "YOUR_EVENT",
"eventdata" => "ANY_DATA",
"visit" => json_encode(array(
        // If you have an email address, assign it here.
        "email" => "",
    )),
));
```

I get that I can use the following CFHTTP calls

```
<cfhttp url="https://trackcmp.net/event" method="POST">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="actid" value="649587205">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="key" value="4a2f544b998d0107cd0341e799513c7eb94abde4">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="event" value="Watched">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="eventdata" value="Video 101 - how to...">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit" value="">
```

But how do I handle the "visit" call

```
"visit" => json_encode(array(
    // If you have an email address, assign it here.
    "email" => "",
)),
```

I have the email address just confused on how to convert this to CF tag logic.
Thanks.
Matt

Comment: In the PHP, each item is being put into an array (ordered map). The value for the array key "visit" is itself an array with the one key of "email". In ColdFusion an array is an array, not an ordered map. An Ordered Map is essentially a Structure in ColdFusion. I would code this in ColdFusion as <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit" value="#serializeJSON(visit{email,"myemailaddress"})#">

Comment: Does `json_encode` convert the array to a string? this should look like either `<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit" value="#serializeJSON( [ { "email" = "" }, { "email" = "" } ] )#">` or maybe `<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit" value="#serializeJSON( { "email" = "",... } )#">`  in ColdFusion

Answer (score 2):

Best to start with the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/docs.php) to figure out what those two functions are doing.

**array()**

The documentation for the [array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) function, and [array type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), it explains that in this context it creates an associative array or in other words, a CF structure.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates *values* to *keys*.

**json_encode()**

As implied by the name, [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encodes the associative array object as a string, in JSON format.

**CF Code**

The CF equivalent is to create a structure. Then use [serializeJSON()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) to convert it into a string. Using structure literal syntax, it's extremely similar

```
 #serializeJSON( {"email":"abc@example.com"} )#
```

Just remember to wrap key names in quotes to prevent CF from converting key names to upper case when serializing. Also, one big difference between PHP and CF is that PHP structures are *ordered* by default. CF structures aren't. In this simple example, order shouldn't matter, but it can make a difference when serializing. If you *do* need an ordered structure, see this thread:

["How to fix `remove default alphabetical ordering of SerializeJSON() `](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738639/how-to-fix-remove-default-alphabetical-ordering-of-serializejson)

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports arrays in its Form fields while ColdFusion does not. With ColdFusion, PHP "arrays" are basically strings that look and act like arrays, so you can "fake" the array. Your `visit` form field would look like this:

```
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit[email]" value="">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="visit[whatever]" value="">
```